# bottleneck using entity framework inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

so first my entities

[image: Entities]

the problem i want to have a page with all the story titles and their types

there are three stories `LongStory` , `CoOpStory`, `GenericStory`

the generic story is associated with `StoryType` for the type of the generic story

i have two problems

first when i want to check if the story is `LongStory` or `CoOpStory` i have to get all the entity and check the entity type if it is `LongStory` then do something , i don't know how to retrieve some data [only the title] and check the type

my second problem like i said i want to have a page with all the story titles and their types i don't know how to do that without making a lot of queries , i can't make a join to the `StoryType` table because it must be `GenericStory` to be associated with that , so what i do first get all the stories then do an extra query for every `GenericStory` to get the type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking of `OfType` and `Concat` extension methods.

To get only LongStory instances you just need to call:

```
var longStories = context.Stories.OfType<LongStory>().ToList();
```

To get your bigger query it is little bit more complex. You can either try:

```
var allStories = context.Stories
                        .OfType<GenericStory>()
                        .Include("StoryType") // I'm not sure how this works with concat
                        .Concat(
                             context.Stories.OfType<LongStory>.Concat(         
                                  context.Stories.OfType<CoOpStory>()));
```

Or you can do a projection:

```
var allStories = context.Stories
                        .OfType<GenericStory>()
                        .Select(s => new { s.Title, s.StoryType.Name })
                        .Concat(
                             context.Stories
                                    .OfType<LongStory>
                                    .Select(s => new { s.Title, "LongStory" })
                                    .Concat(         
                                        context.Stories
                                               .OfType<CoOpStory>()
                                               .Select(s => new { s.Title, Type })));
```

Comment: lol, I just stopped writing :) Are the `allStories` queries are actually three roundtrips to DB? I also had `Concat` in mind but the parameter is `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`. I wasn't sure if we get three roundrips then. The `context.Stories.OfType<LongStory>.Concat(context.Stories.OfType<CoOpStory>())` could possibly compressed into `context.Stories.Where(s => !(s is GenericStory))`.

Comment: `Concat` is translated to `UNION ALL` and `Union` simply to `UNION`. If not there is no way to do union in linq-to-entities. That compression is cool :) I thought about the way how to avoid two concatenations but this didn't come to my mind.

Comment: Good to know how `Concat` translates! Finally I've found something ugly (but working) for the first part of the question. I'm wondering if this really isn't possible in an easier way.

Comment: when using `Concat` in your first example you can't because you are Concatenating different types `GenericStory` with `LongStory` with `CoOpStory`

Comment: so you have to do a projection first if you want to cancat ?

Comment: Good point with different types. The projection looks like the only way.

Answer (score 3):

Ladislav's answer is for your second question. Here is a possible solution to your first question.

As far as I can see you cannot query directly the type in an projection (using `GetType()` for instance won't work in LINQ to Entities). But the following will work if you want for instance only query the title and the type of a story:

```
var stories = context.Stories
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Title = s.Title,
        Type = (s is LongStory) ? "LongStory" :
               (s is CoOpStory) ? "CoOpStory" :
               (s is GenericStory) ? "GenericStory" :
               (s is Story) ? "Story" : // forget this if Story is abstract
               "Unknown"
    }).ToList();
```

You would get a list of anonymous objects where the `Type` property represents the type as your custom string in this query.

Not very nice because you had to change this query every time you add a new class to the hierarchy. Also the order matters (most derived classes must be first in the expression for the `Type` property). But I don't know another way.

Comment: sorry can't mark both as answer but really great info , thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
context.Stories.OfType<LongStory>.Where(...).Cast<Story>()
 .Union(context.Stories.OfType<GenericStory>.‌​Where(...).Include(s => s.StoryType).Cast<Story>())
 .Union(context.Stories.OfType<CoOpStory>.Where(...).Cast<Story>());
```

Comment: This looked really good and solves the problem to concat the different type collections. Unfortunately EF complains that the `Include` path is invalid and `StoryType` is not a declared property on type `Story`, I just tested it. It seems that the `Include` is applied to the `DbSet<Story>` before `OfType<GenericStory>()` actually gets applied.