# How do I deeply eager load an entity with a reference to an instance of a persistent base type (Entity Framework 4)

Tags: entity-framework-4

[image: Domain Model]

Above is a simplified version of our domain model. `NotificationOrder` has a reference to an instance of a sub class (consider `ReferenceNumberBase` logically abstract).

**Problem:**

I want a query to return all `NotificationOrders` that satisfies XYZ and I want that query to eagerly load all referenced instances of `CustomerCase` (including all related objects of that graph, except `Group` forget about that issue for the moment).

I've tried searching for a solution to this, but all I've found are solutions to problems equivalent of querying for `CustomerCase` as a root object directly.

I'd like something like this:

```
    var query = ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<NotificationOrder>.Where(e => e.NotificationType == "Foo");
    return ((ObjectSet<NotificationOrder>) query).Include("ReferenceNumberBase");
```

However, that won't load the `Vehicle` instance of `CustomerCase` or any of the other related objects. How can I express this so EF understands the eager load I want (I'd very much like to avoid multiple roundtrips / notification order)?

NOTE: Since `CustomerCase` is a derived type I can't do normal transitive include using something like this:

```
    var query = ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<NotificationOrder>.Where(e => e.NotificationType == "Foo");
    return ((ObjectSet<NotificationOrder>) query).Include("ReferenceNumberBase.Vehicle"); //
```

since the `Vehicle` property is a member of the derived `CustomerCase` type, and not the `ReferenceNumberBas`e type and instead we get errors like:

"The EntityType 'Model.ReferenceNumberBase' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Vehicle'."

Neither can I use `query.OfType<CustomerCase>...` since the query type is `NotificationOrder`, and not ReferenceNumberBase (or can I somehow?).

ps. We are using self tracking POCO entities with EF4 (have not upgraded to 4.1 yet)

EDIT: I've searched some more, and as of about a year ago this looks to have been a limitation of the Include() method (at least at that time). Is this accurate and has this been adressed since then? [sources below]

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a30351ab-5024-49a5-9eb4-798043a2b75d

http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1057763-inheritance-eager-loading?ref=title

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594289/in-entity-framework-there-should-be-a-way-to-eager-load-include-navigation-properties-of-a-derived-class

Comment: I believe this was a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6586574/270591) and according to the accepted answer and the comments to this answer the only way is using a projection if you want to have a single roundtrip.

Comment: No. That question/answer is the equivalent of querying for ReferenceNumberBase instances directly and expecting both Group and CustomerCase instances to be deeply eager loaded with all reference properties. That problem is solvable, for instance using OfType<T> (....OfType<CustomerCase>.....Union(....OfType<Group>)....)

Comment: True, the example in the other question is even simpler than your case. Can you explain your solution as an answer to the former question because that would be a very important result if the problem is solvable. (I have some doubt though, because you seem to try a union between different type collections (`CustomerCase` and `Group`) which looks like the same situation why also `Concat` doesn't work, see comments to accepted answer.)

Comment: OTTOMH query.OfType<LongStory>.Where(...).Cast<Story>.Union(query.OfType<GenericStory>.Where(...).Cast<Story>).Union... Again, that is how to deal with that question I think, but wont solve our problem in this post