# Entity Framework: Eager Loading Navigation Properties of Inherited Entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to eager load my entire graph and it looks like the following:

```
public class WorkoutProgram
{
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}

public class Schedule
{
    public ICollection<DayBase> Days { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DayBase
{
}

public class TrainingDay : DayBase
{
    public ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
}

context.WorkoutPrograms.Include("Schedule.Days.Exercises");
```

Obviously, not all `Schedule.Days` are `TrainingDay`s, so I get a runtime error because of the path including `Exercises`.

Am I missing a configuration here, or do I need to resort to lazy loading (which I hope not).

Thanks

Comment: No solutions have been found yet for eager loading according to these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6586574/270591 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7203303/270591

Comment: this plus not supporting interface based entities tells me EF is great for simple CRUD apps but is limited "out of the box" for enterprise ready apps.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like many developers are having pain of this issue, including me.

### [Please cast your vote!!!](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594289/in-entity-framework-there-should-be-a-way-to-eager-load-include-navigation-properties-of-a-derived-class)