# Eagerly Load Navigation Property that is List<OfSomeBaseClass>

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Using EF Code First and given an Entity that contains a List, how can I eagerly load the entire object graph for that entity:

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<BarBase> Bars { get; set; }
}    

public class BarBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class BarTypeA : BarBase
{
    public List<Baz> Bazes { get; set; }
}    

public class BarTypeB : BarBase
{
    public List<Quux> Quuces { get; set; } { get; set; }
}
```

If `BarBase` were not a base class that could contain instances of several different subtypes, I could use

```
.Include("Bars").Include("Bars.Bazes")
```

If I try

```
.Include("BarBase").Include("BarBase.Bazes").Include("BarBase.Quuces")
```

I get the error

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'BarBase' does
>   not declare a navigation property with the name 'Bazes'.

But how do I handle the situation that `Bars` can contain different concrete types, and I want to eagerly load all of those instances including the `List<T>` contained in those concrete types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [reported problem](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-include-property-of-derived-classes) in EF currently without a solution.

Comment: This similar question has an accepted solution, but I don't understand the solution.  Do you agree that the accepted answer will solve this category of problems?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635152/entity-framework-eager-loading-of-subclass-related-objects

Comment: Yes it should work. It is nice workaround but it probably produces complex SQL query.