# Loading something from database causes null variable .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to load something from the database in visual studio, which works. However, the object I'm getting has some variables that are null:

I'm loading an instance of class 'ClauseComponent'. This object has 2 properties of type 'ClauseComponent'. These 2 properties are null.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the variables while debugging]

Code from the repository:

```
Grade gr = grades.Include(l => l.DeterminateTableProp.ClauseComponent)
    .FirstOrDefault(g => g.GradeId == gradeId);
```

Code from the ClauseComponent mapper:

```
public ClauseComponentsMapper()
{
    ToTable("ClauseComponents");

    // Primary key
    HasKey(c => c.ClauseComponentId);

    // Properties
    Property(c => c.ClauseComponentId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

}
```

Code from the Clause class (that is inheriting from the ClauseComponent class):

```
public virtual ClauseComponent YesClause { get; set; }
        public virtual ClauseComponent NoClause { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; private set; }

        public virtual Parameter Par1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Parameter Par2 { get; set; }
        public int Waarde;

        public Clause(String name, Parameter par1, int waarde)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Par1 = par1;
            this.Waarde = waarde;
        }

        public Clause(String name, Parameter par1, Parameter par2)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Par1 = par1;
            this.Par2 = par2;
        }

        public Clause()
        {

        }
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Null values in the database?

Comment: Nope, as you can see here:
http://i.imgur.com/9HV9A6r.jpg

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?  Debug it or use Wireshark to see what query is actually being executed.

Comment: Yes this is entity framework. I will asap post the query. Not at pc now.

Comment: {SELECT     [Extent1].[GradeId] AS [GradeId],     [Extent1].[name] AS [name],     [Extent1].[DeterminateTableProp_DeterminateTableId] AS [DeterminateTableProp_DeterminateTableId]    FROM [dbo].[Grades] AS [Extent1]}

Comment: You're trying to eager load two entities that are only specified on a subclass of another entity that is also being loaded. Not really sure how EF works on this.. Going to check that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to disable lazy loading in the ProjectContext class:

```
//this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Unfortunately I don't think EF can handle eager loading on properties only referent to sub-classes (TPH).

There are workarounds using projections, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635152/entity-framework-eager-loading-of-subclass-related-objects) but they're not pretty.

Comment: I should do this with lazy loading, but how?

Comment: Try to understand this workaround on the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635152/entity-framework-eager-loading-of-subclass-related-objects)

Comment: I dont think its the same issue.