# Entity Framework doesn't query derived classes - Error in DbOfTypeExpression

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, polymorphism, entity-framework-5

I have a base class and two derived classes.

Each of the derived classes implements the same type  as a property - the only difference is the property name.

*Sadly I don't have much influence on the class design -> they have been generated from a wsdl file.*

I then have a property on the BaseType to encapsulate the common property. The plan was to use this property in my web views etc.

I have used the famous "Fruit-Example" to demonstrate the problem:

```
 public class FruitBase
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }


        //
        // The plan is to use this property in mvc view
        //
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual FruitnessFactor Fruitness
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Apple))
                    return ((Apple)this).AppleFruitness;
                else if (this.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Orange))
                    return ((Orange)this).OrangeFruitness;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

public class FruitnessFactor { }
```

In my MVC controller, the following query works absolutely fine:

```
return View(context.FruitEntities
                           .OfType<Apple>().Include(a =>a.AppleFruitness)
                           .ToList());
```

But this one doesn't:

```
  return View(context.FruitEntities
                                   .OfType<Apple>().Include(a =>a.AppleFruitness)
                                   .OfType<Orange>().Include(o => o.OrangeFruitness)
                                   .ToList());
```

The error message I get is:

***DbOfTypeExpression requires an expression argument with a polymorphic result type that is compatible with the type argument.***

I am using EF 5.0 RC and the Code First approach.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This maybe because your expression implies `Orange` is an `Apple`

Comment: I would have thought by defining my FruitEntities as `DbSet<FruitBase> FruitEntities` the expression implies that Orange and Apple are Fruits?!

Comment: The `OfType` chain says: "Filter all apples from the FruitEntities and then filter from the result all apples that are oranges" which only makes sense if oranges are apples, i.e. `Orange` class inherits from `Apple` class. What do you want to achieve with that query? A combined list of oranges and apples, i.e. all fruits that are apples **or** oranges?

Comment: I want to return a list of all fruites to a view and then display FruitBase.FruitnessFactor. I can see how the `OfType` doesn't make sense in this context. The "manual" alternative would be to query for oranges and then apples, merging both into on List<fruits>. That seems to work but the code smells

Comment: Actually, what smells is manually querying the subtypes. Relying on polymorphism is the right way.

Comment: Totally agree but still no answer to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell you can't apply `Include` on multiple subtypes in a single database query. You can query one type (`OfType<Apple>().Include(a => a.AppelFruitness)`) and the same for another subtype. The problem is that you can't concat the results in the same query because the result collections have different generic types (apples and oranges).

One option would be to run two queries and copy the result collection into a new collection of the base type - as you already indicated in the comment section under your question.

The other option (which would only need a single query) is a projection. You would have to define a projection type (you could also project into an anonymous type)...

```
public class FruitViewModel
{
    public FruitBase Fruit { get; set; }
    public FruitnessFactor Factor { get; set; }
}
```

...and then can use the query:

```
List<FruitViewModel> fruitViewModels = context.FruitEntities
    .OfType<Apple>()
    .Select(a => new FruitViewModel
    {
        Fruit = a,
        Factor = a.AppleFruitness
    })
    .Concat(context.FruitEntities
    .OfType<Orange>()
    .Select(o => new FruitViewModel
    {
        Fruit = o,
        Factor = o.OrangeFruitness
    }))
    .ToList();
```

If you don't disable change tracking (by using `AsNoTracking`) the navigation properties get populated automatically when the entities get attached to the context ("Relationship fixup") which means that you can extract the fruits from the viewModel collection...

```
IEnumerable<FruitBase> fruits = fruitViewModels.Select(fv => fv.Fruit);
```

...and you'll get the fruits *including* the `FruitnessFactor` properties.

This code is pretty awkward but a direct approach without using a projection has been asked for several times without success:

- [bottleneck using entity framework inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586574/bottleneck-using-entity-framework-inheritance)
- [Entity Framework - Eager loading of subclass related objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635152/entity-framework-eager-loading-of-subclass-related-objects)
- [How do I deeply eager load an entity with a reference to an instance of a persistent base type (Entity Framework 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203303/how-do-i-deeply-eager-load-an-entity-with-a-reference-to-an-instance-of-a-persis)

Comment: I think I am going for the 2 query solution. I only fear a performance impact if one takes into account that I need to do sorting, pagination and stuff like that. But so far it's looking good. Cheers!