# Loading related objects without Include()

Tags: entity-framework

Briefly, I'm loading objects that descend from a base class using a repository defined against the base class.  Although my objects are created with the correct descendant classes, any descendant classes that add navigation properties not present in the base class do not have those related objects loaded, and I have no way to explicitly request them.

Here is a simple method in a repository class that loads a given calendar event assuming you know its ID value:

```
    public CalendarEvent GetEvent(int eventId)
    {
        using (var context = new CalendarEventDbContext(ConnectionString))
        {

            var result = (from evt in context.CalendarEvents
                          where eventId.Equals((int)evt.EventId)
                          select evt).ToList();

            return result.ToList()[0];
        }
    }
```

`CalendarEvent` is a base class from which a large number of more specific classes descend.  Entity Framework correctly determines the actual class of the calendar event specified by `eventId` and constructs and returns that derived class.  This works perfectly.

Now, however, I have a descendant of `CalendarEvent` called `ReportIssued`.  This object has a reference to another object called `ReportRequest` (another descendant of `CalendarEvent`, although I don't think that's important).

My problem is that when Entity Framework creates an instance of `ReportIssued` on my behalf I *always* want it to create and load the related instance of `ReportRequested`, but because I am creating the event in the context of generic calendar events, although I correctly get back a `ReportIssued` event, I cannot specify the `.Include()` to get the related object. I want to do it through this generically-expressed search because I won't necessarily know the type of `eventId`'s event and also I have several other "Get" methods that return collections of `CalendarEvent` descendants.

I create my mappings using the Fluent API.  I guess what I'm looking for is some way to express, in the mapping, that the related object is always wanted or, failing that, some kind of decorator that expresses the same concept.

I find it odd that when *saving* objects Entity Framework always walks the entire graph whereas it does not do the equivalent when *loading* objects.

Comment: Can you use the string overload of Include, not certain it works but might be a good starting point?

Comment: Also, just a comment on the code you have there - use FirstOrDefault rather than ToList. FirstOrDefault will ensure a SELECT TOP 1 is used at the database, plus it's more obvious what the method is actually doing!

Comment: Dean: Code is simplified, it actually does check and return `null` if nothing is returned.  Also, I tried the string overload and Entity Framework checks the base type, not the eventually instantiated type and, alas, throws an exception.

Comment: Only option would be to check the type before you return and perform another query to retrieve the relations for that particular type... Sucks but I don't think you can do it any other way :(

Comment: Slauma has sank his teeth into this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11040057/861716) with only limited success. We need an `Include<TSub>()` method.