# LINQ to SQL, select from an inheritted class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, inheritance

Using LINQ to SQL and Object Relational Designing; Let's say we have a `class Animal` with two inherited classes, named `Cat` and `Dog`. We can load the "Animal" class and its properties easily:

```
var animals = from a in dataContext.Animals
              select a;
```

However, when trying to load `Cat` or `Dog`, dataContext has the attribute of neither `Cats` nor `Dogs`. How is it possible to load a `Cat` or a `Dog` from the table `Animal` with their own extra properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"How is it possible to load a Cat or a Dog from the table Animal with their own extra properties?"_ - you can't. Will `Animal animal = new Animal(); Cat cat = (Cat)animal;` compile? Explain the situation a bit more (what classes did you define, what code do you currently have, what have you tried).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
var dogs = from a in dataContext.Animals.OfType<Dog>()
              select a;
```

and for cats:

```
var cats = from a in dataContext.Animals.OfType<Cat>()
              select a;
```

Like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586574/bottleneck-using-entity-framework-inheritance)

... and a complete example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545395/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Understanding-Table-Per-Ty)

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Project into a new Cat or a new Dog:

**Cat:**

```
var animals = from a in dataContext.Animals
              select new Cat {
                  CatProperty = a.Property
              };
```

Dog:

```
var animals = from a in dataContext.Animals
              select new Dog {
                  DogProperty = a.Property
              };
```

Comment: didn't work for me. "a" has no access to the attribute of "Property". . .